# Drawing a square layout inside a circle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a relative layout bounded within a circle i.e the relative layout should be like the square shown in the figure below.

I am trying to set width and height of the layout as:

`√((diameter)²/2)` which is about 70 %

[image: square inside a circle]
<sub>(source: [yogaflavoredlife.com](http://www.yogaflavoredlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/square-circle.gif))</sub>

```
public class SquareLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int originalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int originalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int required = Math.min(originalWidth, originalHeight) * 7 / 10;

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(required, required);
    }
}
```

What I am getting is a rectangular layout instead of square layout:

[image]

Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong?

Sample usage:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.widget.SquareLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F55C5C">

    </com.example.widget.SquareLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i try your code and i am getting a square, may it got to do with other views nearby.

Comment: I am getting a rectangular one.

Comment: Can you give the full SquareFrameInsideCircle view? I think this has something to do with the square height not matching the circle height. Especially since you use `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);` instead of passing required.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong class name. It is the same SquareLayout. Check the updated sample usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got the solution. First I created a square frame to hold all the layouts.

```
public class SquareFrame extends FrameLayout {
    public SquareFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int originalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int originalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int required = Math.min(originalWidth, originalHeight);

        super.onMeasure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(required, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(required, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

Then inserted all layouts within that square frame.

```
<com.example.widget.SquareFrame 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#5CF5FC">

    <com.example.widget.SquareLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F55C5C">

    </com.example.widget.SquareLayout>

</com.example.widget.SquareFrame>
```

Here is what I got
[image] a square, not a rectangle.